# Where's the pie chart in Firefox that showed you how much time it took for each asset to download gone?

Tags: javascript, web, firefox, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

There used to be a pie chart in the Network tab that showed you performance statistics like:

- How many assets were there on the page?
- How many were retrieved from the cache?
- How many HTTP requests had to be made?
- How much time each HTTP request took?
- etc.

It looked like this:

[image]

Where is that gone now? I can't find it in Firefox version 66?

Actually, I can't even be sure if it was Firefox or Chrome but it was definitely one among the two and I can't find anything that looks like that any longer on any of the newer versions of either Firefox or Chrome (I am now using version 73).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you correctly, it's still there, you will need to click on `Start performance analysis` button in [Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) tab. (left bottom corner, timer icon, see below screenshot) (*as of v66.x*)

[image]

It will give you this:

[image]

*p.s: I'm not sure about Chrome.*

Comment: Oh yes, I totally missed looking at that. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Hey, I see them but the two pies are always in *loading* state. They never show the data no matter how long I wait.

Comment: For me it works well, would you test on another site (if you didn't), for example this page of stackoverflow? I think you using latest version of FF, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest version of Firefox, which I downloaded less than 2 weeks ago. And I tested many websites. They all load but the two pies remain grey. I made a separate question for this so I could show everyone the picture I am seeing: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55663238/303685