# Firefox Performance Analysis Tool showing two greyed out circles in loading state instead of a pie chart with values

Tags: firefox, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

On Firefox 66 on Windows 10, I see the performance analysis tool in the **Network** tab of the **Developer Tools**.

[image]

I click the **stop watch** icon to start performance analysis for the requests.

But I see the pie charts greyed out and in the *loading* state always, no matter how long I wait.

[image]

Why aren't they showing the performance metrics? Do I have to turn some setting on?

Comment: Refresh Firefox (_head to `about:support`_), (or use brand new profile) and test again

Comment: Thank you. :-) `Refresh Firefox` did it. It is working now. :-) If you put it as an answer, others will also benefit.

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce this problem on a fresh Firefox 66 profile. Searching in the bug tracker brought me to [bug 1430698](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1430698).

According to the info there, Setting `network.http.rcwn.enabled` to `false` via [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) solves the problem, and it did work for me. Having said that, it is unclear to me what this option actually does, so use it at your own risk.

Comment: I could find this option @ [about:config entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries) _I don't know if that list is updated or not_, any idea what `rcwn` is stand for?

Comment: I just searched a bit about `rcwn` and it means `Race Cache with Network`. That's to tell the browser to fire off both -- a cache retrieval from the cache on the hard disk, as well as an HTTP request to get the resource from the server -- and let them both race and to get the resource from whichever wins the race. This is useful for people using older hard disks where hard disk access time might be slower than getting the resource over a high-speed internet connection.

Comment: Also, after turning off the said flag, it does work only for some websites. For example, it doesn't work for my website https://sathyaish.net, and it also doesn't work for this website https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/84wrie/more_about_race_cache_with_network_in_firefox_59/ I observe that it works for simple websites that simply load static assets and then remain silent. For e.g. this website http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.memory.enable If a website, after having loaded content initially, still makes ajax requests, it doesn't work for it.

Comment: Ok, I am observing that if I clear my browser cache, it works, but only for that time. As soon as the cache has been primed, and then I reload the page either by refreshing the browser (f5) or doing a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5), it shows the greyed out boxes again. Also, when it does work only for the first time after you have cleared your browser cache/storage, both the values -- the ones for *Empty Cache* and those for *Primed Cache* read exactly the same, so no proper comparison can be made of the two states.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 try enable `Disable Cache` option is Network tab. so Firefox doesn't cache anything and you are good to go

Comment: @MehdiDehghani This option doesn't have an influence on the performance analysis, because that tool is explicitly designed to compare cached vs. non-cached requests.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 I've [mentioned your question here in the bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1430698#c3) for reference. I suggest you follow it and post more findings there.

Comment: @SebastianZartner I tested with `Disable Cache` enabled and I got 2 different result (_for cached vs. non-cached requests_)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Interesting! In my tests they were always the same, sometimes just differed in 1 or 2 KB, though I also did them on dynamic pages. If you experience a difference on static pages with and without the option enabled, I think you should file another bug for it, because that behavior seems wrong.

Comment: @SebastianZartner if it works fine for you, I think they never approve it as a bug, am I right? would you test for current _SO_ page and share the result and then I compare that to my result.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Sorry for the delay! I've created [two screenshots of the analysis of this site](https://imgur.com/a/STH156I) (with an adblocker installed to avoid differences due to different ads). If it looks different for you and you want to ensure your bug report gets approved, you need to find a way to make it reproducible. Mozilla provides some [guidelines for how to report a bug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Bug_writing_guidelines).

Comment: @SebastianZartner don't worry, thank you for the screenshots, as you tested (I think) in new/clean profile, I did the same and I got almost same as yours, I think in my main profile there is some addon or something that cause the that result. so Firefox is good on this one, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You need to refresh the Firefox.

From [Reset Firefox preferences to troubleshoot and fix problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems)

> Resetting preferences (zoom, tabs, privacy, network, encryption, updates, where to save file downloads, etc.) is one of many procedures that can be helpful.

You can refresh Firefox using following steps (*as of `v66.x`*):

1. Open up Firefox
2. Head to `about:support`
3. Click on `Refresh Firefox ...` button (*Firefox will close to refresh itself*)

Note: (*from mentioned article*)

> When using the refresh feature, your bookmarks, browsing history, open tabs, windows, passwords, cookies and web form auto-fill information will be saved. However, your extensions and themes will be removed and your preferences will be reset.

Comment: It came back and then it went away again.

Comment: If you didn't change anything (since you refresh the Firefox) also didn't add any addon, I think you should report it as a bug (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) (_btw in my test everything works fine_)